# Twilio.Sync map frequently cannot get 300 over items

Tags: javascript, synchronization, twilio

I'm developing Twilio Sync.

I use Map, insert items over 300 items.

To get all items, I call function `getItems`.

Get per 50 items, recursive call get all items.

Then, frequently throws below error.

1. sync.js throws exception and messages is `Maximum attempt time limit reached`.

But Http Status Code is 200.

2. Exception message is `Rate limit exceeded for read-map-MAPSID`.

Http Status Code is 429.

These errors throws frequently, but rarely success.

How can I get *stable* all map items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the Product Lead of Sync. I believe we've seen this problem before and it's likely one of the below:

1. Calling `getItems` periodically (instead of relying on ["itemUpdated" events](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/sync/releases/0.7.1/docs/Map.html#event:itemUpdated)),
2. Calling `getItems` too often (i.e. for every mouse click), or
3. Paging incorrectly.

I don't know which affects you most specifically, but the second is most illustrative.

### Querying Items too often (don't do this):

```js
$('#something').mouseUp(event => {
  …
  mySyncMap.getItems(/* everything */)
    .then(paginator => {
      displayInUi(paginator.items);
    });
});
```

This seems inoccuous, but because there is no concrete start-and-end to the query, Sync can't use locally cached data. It will query everything again, which will cause you to hit [Sync rate limits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/sync-limits), specifically the "rate of object reads". Since you're seeing HTTP 429 errors, this is probably what's happening.

### Query once, and then update the UI in pieces.

In most cases, you should not use `getItems()` inside UI event handlers. Instead, **use a local collection to store queried items** after initialization:

```js
let everything = {}
let pageHandler = function(paginator) {
  paginator.items.forEach(function(item) {
    everything[item.key] = item.value;
  });

  if (paginator.hasNextPage) {
    return paginator.nextPage().then(pageHandler);
  } else {
    drawUiWith(everything)
    return null;
};

map.getItems({ from: 'myKey', order: 'asc' })
  .then(pageHandler)
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Map getItems() failed', error);
  });
```

… and redraw when the items change.

```js
map.on('itemUpdated', event => {
  if (! event.isLocal)  # echo suppression, perhaps
    everything[event.item.key] = item.value;
    drawUiWith(everything);
});
```

Even more efficient would be to have a `drawOneItem` function, but sometimes that's not practical.

### About Infinite Loops

Infinite loops are a tough error to diagnose without seeing your code, but it's not an uncommon error. We added a [code snippet for paging over map items](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/sync/releases/0.7.1/docs/Map.html#getItems) to our more recent SDKs' documentation. Perhaps that will help.

**I hope that helps!**

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

My program call getItems() when open webpage every times.

And users are 300 overs.

I think querying often too much.

So, I will modify my program, not query every times.

Try to change Query once.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/sync-limits
May I ask additional question?According to above document, Rate of
Object Writes/Reads `20/s per object `. This `object` means per map? Or per mapItem?

Comment: That's per map, @西口瑛一. :)